# Compiling Hello World

Tags: java, android

I'm working from a simple "hello world" tutorial and then modify it into the app I want. I started out with a hello world app added a button and now I'm tryin to respond to button events, etc.

But when I compile I'm getting the error: "package andriod.widget does not exist \n import andriod.widget.Button;"

The code is

```
package com.luke.bowls;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import andriod.widget.Button;

public class Bowls extends Activity
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
                final Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.android_button);
                button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // Perform action on clicks
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

It looks like a library reference problem but most of build code is hidden from me so I have no idea what to do to fix it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've mis-spelt android...

Comment: LOL! hate it when that happens

Comment: hehe don't worry I've done worse.  I once rewrote a 5000 line homework assignment because I spelled Scanner as Scaner...

Comment: @Mechko - hence the importance of teaching children to SPELL in primary school.

Answer (score 4):

if you use Eclipse, you should press Ctrl+Shift+O to automatically import the needed libraries instead of manually typing it :)

Comment: If eclipse worked at all for me I might have tried it but the plugin installer was completely non functional.

Comment: Did you mean the ADT plugin? Because that is a remote update site so I think the problem would be the internet connection itself.

Comment: +1 for using the ADT.  It will make your life considerably easier.

Answer (score 0):

maud-dib, I've sometimes had trouble downloading the eclipse plugin, but have always gotten it to work by manually downloading the plugin zip file and installing it in eclipse as local/archive plugin.